# Logistic regression using gradient descent

Tags: performance, c

My code seems to work fine, but I'm interested in how I can make it faster. I really just want to reduce any wasteful computation (for instance `eta_m = eta / (double)m` reduces `coef[j] -= eta * gradient_coef[j] / (double)m` to `coef[j] -= eta_m * gradient_coef[j]`). I realize a good BLAS implementation would probably be useful, but I've found that complicates usage on other systems (unless there's some generalized implementation out there).

I've tried to take advantage of some linear properties (where able) to reduce the number of loops performed, though the initial loop that sets coefficients and gradients to 0.0 could probably be wrapped into the main loops using if statements. The alpha and beta declarations are vestigial from using BLAS but can't imagine they're very impactful. Anything glaringly inefficient that I'm missing here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Compute z = w * x + b
double dlc( unsigned long n, double *X, double *coef, double intercept )
{
    double z = intercept;
    for ( unsigned long j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        z += X[j] * coef[j];
    }
    return z;
}

// Compute y_hat = 1 / (1 + e^(-z))
double dsigmoid( unsigned long n, double alpha, double *X, double *coef, double beta, double intercept )
{
    //double z = intercept;
    //bli_ddotxv( BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, BLIS_NO_CONJUGATE, n, &alpha, X, 1, coef, 1, &beta, &z );
    double z = dlc(n, X, coef, intercept);
    if ( z >= 0)
    {
      return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-z));
    }
    else
    {
      return exp(z) / (1.0 + exp(z));
    }
}

// Gradient descent
void dgd( unsigned long m, unsigned long n, double *X, double *y, double *coef, double *intercept, double eta, int max_iter, int fit_intercept )
{
    double alpha = 1.0, beta = 1.0, gradient_intercept = 0.0, eta_m;

    double *y_pred = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
    double *resid = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
    double *gradient_coef = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));

    for ( unsigned long j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        coef[j] = 0.0;
        gradient_coef[j] = 0.0;
    }
    *intercept = 0.0;

    eta_m = eta / (double)m;
    
    for ( int epoch = 0; epoch < max_iter; epoch++ )
    {
        // Compute y_hat and gradients
        for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        {
            y_pred[i] = dsigmoid( n, alpha, &X[n*i], coef, beta, *intercept );
            resid[i] = y[i] - y_pred[i];
            for ( unsigned long j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                gradient_coef[j] -= (X[n*i + j] * resid[i]);
            }
            if ( fit_intercept == 1 )
            {
                gradient_intercept -= resid[i];
            }
        }
        // Adjust weights
        for ( unsigned long j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            coef[j] -= eta_m * gradient_coef[j];
            gradient_coef[j] = 0.0;
        }
        if ( fit_intercept == 1 )
        {
            *intercept -= eta_m * gradient_intercept;
            gradient_intercept = 0.0;
        }
    }
    free(y_pred);
    free(resid);
    free(gradient_coef);
}
```

Edit: added code for checking speed of execution.

```
int main(void)
{
    double *X, *y, *coef, *y_preds;
    double intercept, eta = 0.5;
    double alpha = 1.0, beta = 1.0;
    unsigned long m = 100000;
    unsigned long n = 20;
    int max_iter = 250;

    int class_0 = (unsigned long)(3.0 / 4.0 * (double)m);
    double pct_class_1 = 0.0;

    clock_t test_start;
    clock_t test_end;
    double test_time;

    printf("Constructing variables...\n");
    X = (double *) malloc (m * n * sizeof(double));
    y = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
    y_preds = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
    coef = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));

    // Initialize classes
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        if (i < class_0)
        {
            y[i] = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            y[i] = 1.0;
        }
        /*
        // Troubleshooting print
        if (i < 10 || i > m - 10)
        {
            //printf("%f\n", y[i]);
        }
        */
    }

    // Initialize observation features
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        if (i < class_0)
        {
            X[n*i] = 1.0 / (double)m;
        }
        else
        {
            X[n*i] = (double)i / (double)m;
        }
        X[n*i + 1] = (double)i / (double)m;
        for ( unsigned long j = 2; j < n; j++ )
        {
            X[n*i + j] = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        }
        /*
        // Troubleshooting print
        if (i < 10)
        {
            //printf("%f\t%f\n", X[n*i], X[n*i+1]);
        }
        */
    }

    // Fit weights
    printf("Running GD/SGD...\n");
    test_start = clock();
    dgd( m, n, X, y, coef, &intercept, eta, max_iter, 1 );
    test_end = clock();
    test_time = (double)(test_end - test_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken: %f\n", test_time);

    // Compute y_hat and share of observations predicted as class 1
    printf("Making predictions...\n");
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        y_preds[i] = dsigmoid( n, alpha, &X[i*n], coef, beta, intercept );
    }

    printf("Printing results...\n");
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        //printf("%f\n", y_pred[i]);
        if (y_preds[i] > 0.5)
        {
            pct_class_1 += 1.0;
        }
        
        // Troubleshooting print
        if (i < 10 || i > m - 10)
        {
            printf("%g\n", y_preds[i]);
        }
        
    }
    /*
    // Troubleshooting print
    printf("Intercept: %f\n", intercept);
    printf("Coefficients:\n");
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf("%f\n", coef[i]);
    }
    */
    printf("Total observations: %ld\n", m);
    printf("Percent class 1: %f\n", pct_class_1 / (double)m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sufficiently-representative test data? I could just stick something arbitrary in there, but if you have it, that would be nice. Also, what sorts of systems are the target?

Comment: BLAS has ports for quite a lot of systems. Do you have any specific cases where you know it cannot be used?

Comment: @harold, sorry, I should have included a test script.  In an hour I’ll upload the code which allows you to specify number of observations and features (though all but 2 columns are randomized).

Comment: @Reinderien I’m operating under the assumption that another user might not even know what BLAS is.  I use BLIS, which I believe installs custom kernels depending on processor architecture.  I assumed a program compiled this way would run into issues on different architectures, or is that wrong?

Comment: @harold I uploaded some code I was using for testing execution speed/accuracy of the GD algo. If you do end up having a chance to take a look, let me know if there's issues; I originally had these packaged into different files. Don't really have a specific system, I'm trying to keep things generalized for the most part, hence why I'm a bit unsure about BLAS.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw sorry about that.  Thanks for reverting.

Comment: @hillard28 I gave it a detailed look, but without using anything platform specific, I could only increase performance by about 20% on my PC. Significantly more should be possible *with* platform specific techniques, since the platform-agnostic nature of the code meant that it didn't use SIMD at all (there was no autovectorization either, GCC manages to do that but I don't use GCC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how I can make it faster (?)

At this time, I see no [big O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) improvements.

**2x faster?: Use `float`**

If the range and precision requirements are not so high, many implementations have 2x (or more) fast `float` functions.

This inner computation loops would benefit most with this change.

e.g.

```
float z;  // float type
return expf(z) / (1.0f + expf(z)); // float constant, function
```

Of course this is highly dependent on OP's compiler and machine.

**Modest: Moved repeated test**

Test `fit_intercept == 1` once.

```
  if (fit_intercept == 1) {   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
      y_pred[i] = dsigmoid( n, alpha, &X[n*i], coef, beta, *intercept );
      resid[i] = y[i] - y_pred[i];
      for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
        gradient_coef[j] -= (X[n*i + j] * resid[i]);
      }
      gradient_intercept -= resid[i];
    }
 } else {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
     y_pred[i] = dsigmoid( n, alpha, &X[n*i], coef, beta, *intercept );
     resid[i] = y[i] - y_pred[i];
     for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
       gradient_coef[j] -= (X[n*i + j] * resid[i]);
     }
   }
 }
```

**Minor: Use the right size type for array indexing**

`size_t` is the right size for all array indexing.  `unsigned long` may be too big (or *possibly* too small).

```
// double dlc( unsigned long n, double *X, double *coef, double intercept )
double dlc(size_t n, double *X, double *coef, double intercept)
```

Same for `dsigmoid()`, `dgd()`.

**Minor: Use `const` for unchanging referenced data**

Performance: Lessor compilers will benefit.  Good compiler will already know referenced data is not changed.

Functionality: by using `const`, code may be called with `const` arrays.

```
// double dlc( unsigned long n, double *X, double *coef, double intercept )
// double dlc(unsigned long n, const double *X, const double *coef, double intercept)
```

Same for `dsigmoid()`, `dgd()`.

---

Tip

Avoid allocate errors (none were noted here).  Allocate to the size of the referenced object and avoid getting the type wrong.

```
// y_pred = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
// Correct even if `y_red` later changed to a `float *`.
y_pred = malloc (sizeof y_pred[0] * m);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I've made those adjustments. I also made some additional changes to my code on my own so I'm about to update to reflect. Your suggestions were still relevant!

Comment: @hillard28 I added the `float` idea.  Hope it works well for you.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't need the casts (as `malloc()` returns a pointer to void, which is directly convertible to *any* object pointer):

> ```
>     double *y_pred = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
>     double *resid = (double *) malloc (m * sizeof(double));
>     double *gradient_coef = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));
> ```

We also run into Undefined behaviour when allocation fails and `malloc()` therefore returns a *null pointer*, since we dereference it without checking.

I'd replace with

```
    double *const y_pred = malloc(m * sizeof *y_pred);
    double *const resid = malloc(m * sizeof *resid);
    double *const gradient_coef = malloc(n * sizeof *gradient_coef);
    if (!y_pred || !resid || !gradient_coef) {
        free(y_pred);
        free(resid);
        free(gradient_coef);
        return -1;   /* or whatever error indication you prefer /*
    }
```